# How to increase line width (Java Applet)

Tags: java, swing, applet, line

I've been trying to increase the width of line using the setStroke method in Java but the only output I seem to be getting is an error message saying "Cannot find method setStroke".

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.orange);
    g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));
    g.drawLine(5, 5, 480, 5);
 }
```

I've imported

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;          
import java.awt.event.*;    
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [Graphics2D#setStroke()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setStroke%28java.awt.Stroke%29)

Simply downcast it to `Graphics2D` and use it.

For example

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));
```

**NOTE:** Never forget to call `super.paint(g)` in overridden method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change what type you're inputting into your method.

```
public void paint(Graphics2D g){
    g.setColor(Color.orange);
    g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));
    g.drawLine(5, 5, 480, 5);
 }
```

as `Graphics2D` instead of `Graphics`.

EDIT:

This will also work (casting it):

```
public void paint(Graphics2D g){
    Graphics2D twoD = (Graphics2D) g;
    twoD.setColor(Color.orange);
    twoD.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));
    twoD.drawLine(5, 5, 480, 5);
 }
```

Comment: I tried this but then it won't draw the line since it's being converted to 2D. I can go round this by using the syntax to draw 2D lines, thank you.